# How to set baseline when design for Android devices with different dpi?

Tags: android

I am trying to provide our developers with alternative drawable resources (image resolution sizes) for different screen densities. Our users use android devices with screen density from mhdpi all the way to xxhdpi. If I am going to start with image specs for mhdpi devices as the baseline, where should I actually start with pixel-wise?

Comment: Only amount of pixels you have affect anything in the end.

Answer (score 1):

**MDPI (Baseline) (160 dpi Resolution in Photoshop) dimention 320x480px - 1x scale**

MDPI 160 1x

HDPI 240 1.5x

XHDPI 320 2x

XXHDPI 480 3x

XXXHDPI 640 4x  Graphics Assets for Max Device Support

*(StyleGuide for Baseline coz 1 px equals 1 dp. Designers can design in px and Developers can put them as dp.)*

Get more tips here https://vinsol.com/blog/2014/11/20/tips-for-designers-from-a-developer/